# NoReverseMatch at /account/login/ Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name in django 3

Tags: python, html, css, django, authentication

I am new to Django3. Recently I am working on this project where I was using django authentication system for login. I was facing an issue:
NoReverseMatch at /account/login/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

My following code is:

**settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'social_account.apps.SocialAccountConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'social_mass_media.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'social_mass_media.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'social_account/dashboard.html',{'section': 'dashboard'})
```

**urls.py**: (for app):

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    #path('/login', views.login_request, name='login'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

**urls.py**: (project URL):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('social_account.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

**dashboard.html**:

```
{% block title %} Dashboard {% endblock %}
{% block content %} 
{{section}}
    <h1> Dashboard </h1>
    <p> Welcome to your Account! </p>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <ul class="menu">
      <li {% if section == 'dashboard' %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
        <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li {% if section == 'images' %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
        <a href="#">Images</a>
      </li>
      <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
        <a href="#">People</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="user">
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      Hello {{ request.user.first_name }},
      <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'account:login' %}">Log-in</a>
    {% endif %}
  </span>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1> Log-In </h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p> Your username or password is incorrect, please try again! </p>
    {% else %}
        <p> Please Login to view your account </p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class='login-form'>
        <form action="{% url login %}" method="post">
            {{form.as_p}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='submit' value='Log-in'></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

the error is in base.html line no. 13 for class="selected". I am not getting why is it wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the template `login.html`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I have added the login.html file

Comment: You want to write `{% url 'login' %}` _with_ the quotes instead of `{% url login %}` as otherwise `login` is considered a variable and not a string, and since no such variable is present in the context it's value is used as an empty string giving you an error.

Comment: okay, that worked, thank you!!!